# Math Number Sequence Riddle with 4 numbers 8 digits

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Create a number using only the digits 4,4,3,3,2,2,1 and 1. So it can only be eight digits. You have to make sure the ones are separated by one digit, the twos are separated by two digits, the threes are separated with three digits and the fours are separated by four digits.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/8-dimensional-vegetable-kebab

Comment: So *that's* what that question is about!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 41312432. I'm not sure how to explain it much further past that; it's mostly just trial and error.