# Prove that we cannot arrange the cards according to the given rules

Tags: logical-deduction, cards

There are ten pairs of cards with the numbers 0, 0, 1, 1...
8, 8, 9, 9 written on them. Prove that they cannot be laid in a row so that there are exactly n cards between any two cards with equal numbers n on them (for all n = 0, 1,... 9).

> This means, from what I understand, that we need to prove that we cannot arrange them in a row such that all the following conditions are fulfilled :
>
> Cards 0 and 0 have no card between them.
>
> Cards 1 and 1 have 1 card between them.
>
> Cards 2 and 2 have 2 cards between them, etc.

This problem comes from the very interesting book, "Mathematical circles Russian experience" by
Fomin, Genkin and Itenberg . I am unable to solve the problem nor can I find a solution to the problem online. The book hasn't provided a solution either.

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: Hint: checkerboard colouring

Comment: @Auribouros please don't suggest MathOverflow for the kinds of math questions we get here: that site requires *research-level* mathematics and is meant for *professional mathematicians*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 8-dimensional vegetable kebab](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/the-8-dimensional-vegetable-kebab). Especially [the proof](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2064/1649) there, and a comment linking to [Langford pairing Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing).

Comment: @justhalf Hey, nice proof there!

Comment: @JLee, I'm not sure about ignoring 0,0 with only that reasoning. What you said is that if there is a solution to 1-9, then there is a solution to 0-9. But if we don't have a solution to 1-9, there can still be a solution to 0-9 as far as we know (not doing the analysis yet), as the 0,0 can help in the middle, enabling a solution not possible in 1-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple proof:

> Any possible solution will have twenty consecutive digits. Colour the digits on the line alternately (like a 1-d chequerboard) for parity.
>  We must clearly have 10 digits each in black and white positions.
>  Now consider the pairs of numbers.
>  No matter where you place them, the 0's must be adjacent so one will be one on each colour. (Opposite parity positions)
>  The 1's must be separated by a single digit, so will both have the same colour. (Same parity positions)
>  Similary, all the pairs of even digits will be one on each colour.
>  And all the pairs of odd digits will be on the same colour.
>
>  Now count the number of each colour.
>  We have five pairs of even digits, which cover five black and five white positions.
>  Then each odd pair will add two to one total and zero to the other.
>  So no matter how you place them, you will always have an odd number of digits on each colour.
>  So it is not possible to end up with ten digits on each colour.