# Do Langford squares exist?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

A Langford sequence is a permutation of the sequence of 2n numbers 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., n, n in which there is one number between the two 1s, there are two numbers between the two 2s, and more generally the two copies of each number k have k numbers in between them.  An example would be:

3 1 2 1 3 2

Define a Langford square to be a square matrix such that every row and every column is a Langford sequence.  The question is:  Do Langford squares exist?  If so, what is the smallest size of a Langford square?  If they don’t exist, why not?

Comment: I assume you want to rule out the 2-by-2 square of 1's?

Comment: @xnor That wouldn't qualify anyway, as there must be a number between the ones.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'd call that two units apart. I think saying one "number in between" would be clearer.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Do you know the answer to this puzzle?

Comment: @user1502040 I don’t know.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/the-8-dimensional-vegetable-kebab

Comment: @DanielMathias A 2-by-2 square of 0's would qualify though.  Probably the only possible solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Langford squares are not possible.

Consider the middle two rows of a $2n \times 2n$ Langford square. They, like all rows, must contain $n$'s. Any $n$ must have a partner $n$ in its column that's $n+1$ spaces above or below it, but that's off the grid for the middle-row $n$'s.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Strictly speaking this only shows that $n\times n$ Langford squares don't exist for even $n$. (But I think it's fairly trivial to extend it to odd $n$ as well.)

Comment: @N.Virgo Each row and column of a Langford square is by definition a Langford sequence.  A Langford sequence has an even number of entries because the sequence is made of pairs of numbers.  Therefore a Langford square with an odd number of rows or columns is impossible.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson right, of course - sorry for the silly comment!

Comment: @N.Virgo Your comment wasn’t silly; you were being thorough.