# 2x8 Langford Rectangle

Tags: mathematics

I was inspired by this great [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120288/do-langford-squares-exist).

Can you place each number from 1 to 8 twice into a 2x8 grid, such that each pair of numbers $k$ are separated by Manhattan distance $k$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one of the possible answer:

> [image]

the first thing is to put

> 8, since it has to be the farest from each other. then 7, then 6.

The rest

> it comes by itself instantly.

Comment: Nice work! It's similar solution that I got.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping two adjacent and unequal numbers changes each number's part length by 1. Therefore, a Langford rectangle with n pairs is only possible if n and the n'th triangular number have the same parity - that is, if n is congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4.
Here are constructions yielding an infinite family for each remainder:

> [image]

> [image]